# How do I capture non-local packets using WireShark on MacOS?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

This is a pretty simple question.

I'm trying to use WireShark to capture packets using my MacBook Pro 2019. Every time I run a capture on `en0` (my Wi-Fi interface), all I am seeing is packets directed to or coming from my IP address (as well as broadcast packets).

**How do I capture TCP/IP packets that are directed to other devices on my Wi-Fi network?**

Comment: The first thing to check is to make sure you told Wireshark to capture using promiscuous mode.

Comment: I have "enable[d] promiscuous mode on all interfaces."